# Getting "Error: Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040E2F " when running SpImport

Tags: moss2007-security

I am import a list item from one list to another in same farm but different sites using SPExport and SPImport API.
While executing import.run(), it is throwing an exception Error: Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040E2F.

Can anybody suggest what to do.

Thanks 
Somalia

Answer (score 1):

Able to solve it.. While importing is in progress if anyone browses the site, you get this error. So, make sure that the site is stopped from IIS.

Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040E2F - This error means primary key violation.

SO in case anyone else faces the issue.... please make ssu